# Phase discontinuity happens during ifft operation using pyfftw and scipy.fft

Tags: python, fft, pyfftw

When doing ifft of a 2D ndarray using pyfftw, I found the resultant phase is discontinuous in many positions. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pyfftw
from scipy.fft import ifftshift,fftshift
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 256
kx = np.linspace(-np.floor(N/2),np.ceil(N/2)-1,N)
kX,kY = np.meshgrid(kx,kx)
kR = np.sqrt(kX**2 + kY**2)
mask = np.where((kR<=15),1,0)
ifft_obj = pyfftw.builders.ifft2(ifftshift(mask))
wave = fftshift(ifft_obj())

plt.imshow(np.angle(wave),cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()
```

The phase image is as follows
[image]
The minimum phase value is `-3.141592653589793` and the maximum value is `3.141592653589793` and their difference is larger than 2pi. Using scipy.fft just gets the same results.
However, when I turn to Matlab, the result looks more reasonable. My code is:

```
N = 256;
kx = linspace(-floor(N/2),ceil(N/2)-1,N);
[kX,kY] = meshgrid(kx,kx);
kR = sqrt(kX.^2 + kY.^2);
mask = single(kR<=15);
wave = fftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(mask)));
imshow(angle(wave));
caxis([min(angle(wave),[],'all') max(angle(wave),[],'all')]);
axis image; colormap jet;colorbar;
```

The phase image is
[image]

I wonder what leads to the phase discontinuity in python code and how can I correct it.

Comment: The phase discontinuity can be solved by adding a tiny pure complex value like `1j*e-16` to the results. But I still want to know why this happens and whether my solution is suitable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is symmetric, which leads to a purely real transform (phase is 0 for positive and π for negative values). But because of numerical inaccuracies of the FFT algorithm, the result has very small imaginary values. Thus, the phase deviates a little bit from 0 and π. In your colormapped image, small deviations from 0 are not seen, but small deviations from π can lead to values close to -π (as [already discussed by VPfB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321246/7328782)).

MATLAB does not show this issue because MATLAB's `ifft` recognizes that the input is (conjugate) symmetric and outputs a purely real image. It simply ignores those small imaginary values.

You can do the same in Python with

```
wave = np.real_if_close(wave, tol=1000)
```

The tolerance here is `np.finfo(wave.dtype).eps * tol` (2.22 10<sup>-13</sup> for double float). Adjust as necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will try this.

Comment: It really helps me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A phase is best shown as an angle on a unit circle. And a circle does not have a begin and an end. Going around the circle does not create a discontinuity. Adding exactly 2*pi (one trip around the circle) does not change the phase, so +pi and -pi are the same phase. The absolute difference of those two phases is thus not 2*pi, but zero. If you take in account tiny rounding errors, it is almost zero.

My suggestion is to use a "cyclic" color scheme (don't know a better term), where approaching +pi on one end and -pi on the other end colors the graph with the same color.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know -pi and pi are the same mathematically but the difference here influence the final results apparently (I used fft and ifft several times in the following code). So I want to find a way to avoid this difference.

Comment: Cyclic is the right name. [Matplotlib has these built in](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#cyclic).